# Assymptotical equivalence of sum and its upper bound (homework)

Tags: limits, asymptotics, approximation

sorry if the question title is incorrect. I'm doing a homework regarding Big O notation.

$$
\text{Show that} \,\,\, \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\,j} \, \approx n^{\,j+1}
$$
where $\approx$ is defined as: $ f(x) \approx g(x) \iff f(x) \in \mathcal{O}(g(x)) \text{ and } g(x) \in \mathcal{O}(f(x))$

My current approach is that I'm trying to show that (all limits are for $n$ going to infinity, it didn't display correctly when I typed):

$$
\lim \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\,j}}{n^{j+1}} \in \mathbb{R}
$$
using two inequalities
$$
\lim \frac{n^j}{n^{j+1}} \leq \lim \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\,j}}{n^{j+1}} \leq \text{don't know what to put here}
$$
where the third limit should be a real number. Then the middle limit would also be real number and therefore $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{\,j} \in \mathcal{O}(n^{j+1})$.

Analogically, I would need to also show that 
$$
\lim \frac{n^{j+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\,j}} \in \mathbb{R}
$$
and therefore $ n^{j+1} \in \mathcal{O}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{j})$

But I'm having difficulty with even the first inequalities.

So my question is: is my approach correct/effective and if it is, what upper bound should I use? So far every upper bound I came up with had infinite limit which isn't useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk^j}{n^{j+1}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}n\right)^j\;;$$

now what is the largest term in the last sum?

Comment: It's 1. I thought rewriting sum in this way, but couldn't think of a way how to use this fact.

Comment: @loppy: So $$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}n\right)^j\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n1^j=1\;.$$

Comment: Thanks, now it's obvious to me. I guess I can use similar tactic for the second inequality, right?

Comment: @loppy: You’re welcome, and yes, you can use a similar approach.

Comment: I already solved it. Big thanks for your help.

Comment: @loppy: You’re very welcome!